# How to return List of Object using Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

My EmployeeDeatils Object has List of other object inside (employeeData). I am trying to fetch that with some mapping with id

But not sure what I am doing wrong

```
     private List<EmployeeData> getEmployeeMessage(List<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetailList, Employee employee) {

    return employeeDetailList.stream()
        .filter(employeeDetail -> employeeDetail.getEmployeeId() == employee.getEmployeeId())
        .map(employeeDetail -> employeeDetail.getEmployeeData())
        .collect(Collectors.toList);

}
```

Comment: I guess your problem is a compiler error, so I suggest to pay attention to the compiler error and what it says. Otherwise, include the problem in your question.

Comment: Mostly understanding about `map` versus `flatMap` as it sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `EmployeeDetails` class has `List<EmployeeData> getEmployeeData()` field, you can fetch these using:

```java
List<EmployeeData> getEmployeeMessage(List<EmployeeDetails> employeeDetailList, Employee employee) {

        return employeeDetailList.stream()
                .filter(employeeDetail -> employeeDetail.getEmployeeId() == employee.getEmployeeId())
                .flatMap(employeeDetail -> employeeDetail.getEmployeeData().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

    }
```

As @Naman correctly pointed out, you need to pay attention on [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) vs [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) operations.

In this case, a `flatMap` is used because you need a mapping operation *for each element* of your list (returned by `getEmployeeData()`).